# Displaying built-in indicator values in strategy alerts?

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way of using placeholders to display ATR in strategy alerts? 
The same way you would use {{volume}} as it's an inbuilt indicator?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by customizing the alert's message through the new `alert_message=` parameter:

```
a = atr(14)
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=GoLong, alert_message='ATR=' + tostring(a) + ' tradeid=' + tostring(trade_id) +' tp=' + tostring(TakeProfitLevel))
```

Contrary to `alertcondition()` messages in studies, strategy alerts can contain series (dynamic) text.

Once your text messages are configured in your code, you will then need to use the `{{strategy.order.alert_message}}` placeholder when you create the alert from the chart UI.

See here for more info: https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000481368-strategy-alerts/